# ChunkedWriteHandler vs HttpObjectAggregator?

Tags: http, netty

I was hoping to ask for some clarification on the roles of the ChunkedWriteHandler and the HttpObjectAggregator. Do these two effectively do opposite things?

In the following setup:

```
p.addLast("client_codec", new HttpClientCodec());
p.addLast("chunker", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
p.addLast(new ClientHandler());
```

Does having the chunker actually do anything? Since I don't have an HttpObjectAggregator in the pipeline, isn't the data going to by written downstream in chunks anyways? When would I need to use a ChunkedWriteHandler for an HTTP server/client?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the javadocs on the classes... `ChunkedWriteHandler` has nothing to do with HTTP at all. It allows to write implementations of `ChunkedInput` in an "efficient" manner while `HttpObjectAggregator` ensures you only see `FullHttp*` in the handler after it.